# Trying to locate a short sci-fi story regarding projecting one's mental self across great intergalactic distances

Tags: story-identification

I think I read this story in Analog or Astounding Stories quite some time ago. The stories photo was one with a person standing on the outstretched arm of a bear.  Seems each person imagined a different animal to facilitate the process of projection. I've been trying for years but I can't identify the specific magazine and issue. I'm still searching and hopefully someone here has read it as well.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe *The Pritcher Mass* by Gordon R. Dickson, a novel serialized in Analog, 1972. No evidence, though. It does have psionic projection and animal familiars, IIRC.

Answer (score 8):

This IS  *The Pritcher Mass* by Gordon R. Dickson, a novel serialized in Analog, 1972.

The artwork by Frank Kelly Freas which we remember must have been a two-page interior spread.

One of the psionic operators of the Mass describes her perceptions:

> "How do you see the Mass?" he asked.
>   "Like an enormous bear," she answered promptly. "A friendly bear - white, like a polar bear. He's sitting up the way bears do. Maybe you've seen them do it in zoos. They sit with their back up straight and their hind legs straight out before them. He sits like that among the stars, half as big as the universe; and he stretches out one foreleg straight from the shoulder, pointing at whatever I want. All I have to do is walk out along that foreleg to get to anyplace this side of infinity."